# Use 'or' operator to handle KeyError in dict

Tags: python

Is that possible in python `3.7^` to use the `or` operator in case of an invalid key in a `dict` ?

```py
value = myDict['invalidKey'] or 'Default'

print(value)
# Has to show 'Default' and don't raise the [KeyError: 'invalidKey'] exception
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It raises the exception `KeyError: 'invalidKey'`

Comment: They why did you ask if it would work?

Comment: @ScottHunter Sorry I wasn't clear enough. The `print(value)` has to show `Default` and don't raise the `KeyError: 'invalidKey'` exception

Comment: `print` isn't what raised the exception; regardless, you knew it didn't work, so why ask if it would?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in the way you wrote it, because the `[]` operator raises an exception before the right hand side of the `or` expression is even evaluated.

The right way to do it is with the `get` function:

```
value = myDict.get('invalidKey', 'Default')
```

In case the question was more of an academic nature: the second argument defaults to `None`, so you *can* do this:

```
value = myDict.get('invalidKey') or 'Default'
```

But note that (a) this is less Pythonic, and (b) it will return `'Default'` for falsy values that are actually present in `myDict`, like `0`, `None`, `False`, `[]` and `''`.

Comment: Well thanks for your answer this solution has the expected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly. You can use ternary operators. For e.g

```
my_dict = {
    'key': "Wow"
}

value = my_dict.get('key') if 'key' in my_dict.keys() else 'Default'
print(value)
```

Comment: You understand it wrong. When I say that the key is invalid I mean that the key don't exist in the `dict`

Comment: @johannchopin ok i've edited the code. how it's just as you wanted.

Comment: This is redundant: `.get` is not needed if you check beforehand (so you can just use `[]` there), and `.keys()` is not needed either because `in` checks keys by default.